# Is asking for documentation on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Well, my guess is that this is bit of a rhetorical question (answer: **No**, documentation is not software), but I could not find a reference saying so.

This question can serve as that reference.

Comment: Found a dupe in the meanwhile and VTCed as such ;-)